# Typescript update array value where index = value

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

i got this array :

```
array={
 posts:[
   {
     isReported:false,
     id:1,
     title:'عنوان المقال القادم من الخادم رقم 1',
     img:'assets/img/1.jpg',
     userId:31,
     userName:'محمود عبد السلام',
     userImg:'assets/img/1.jpg'
  },
....
  ],
....
 }
```

i want to edit value of `isReported` for example where `id = 3` and set it to true.
how to do this?

Comment: In your code, `array` is not an Array, it is just named `array`. `array` has a property, posts that is an Array.

Comment: `array.posts.filter(post => post.id === 3)[0].isReported = true;` but please fix your names

Comment: there is more than item inside it than posts, but i removed the code it is large.

Comment: Iterate thru the `posts` array and check if `id` is 3, then change the value.

Comment: @down voters for my answer.. reason??

Comment: @Aravind You were using lodash (or was it underscore?) for no reason at all.

Comment: @Aravind Did the user mention anything about Lodash? If not, then don't use it in your answer because they're not using it. Anyways there's no reason to - pure JavaScript is just fine...

Comment: my array has more than this `post` property!!!
should i write them all?!!
why down vote?

Comment: @ToBe why all of the  ?!!?!? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: nothing tanks for answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {

  const data = {
    posts: [{
      isReported: false,
      id: 1,
      title: 'عنوان المقال القادم من الخادم رقم 1',
      img: 'assets/img/1.jpg',
      userId: 31,
      userName: 'محمود عبد السلام',
      userImg: 'assets/img/1.jpg'
    }, {
      isReported: false,
      id: 2,
      title: 'عنوان المقال القادم من الخادم رقم 1',
      img: 'assets/img/1.jpg',
      userId: 31,
      userName: 'محمود عبد السلام',
      userImg: 'assets/img/1.jpg'
    }, {
      isReported: false,
      id: 3,
      title: 'عنوان المقال القادم من الخادم رقم 1',
      img: 'assets/img/1.jpg',
      userId: 31,
      userName: 'محمود عبد السلام',
      userImg: 'assets/img/1.jpg'
    }]
  };

  const post3 = data.posts.filter(post => post.id === 3)[0];

  if (post3) {
    console.log(post3);

    post3.isReported = true;

    console.log(post3);
  }

}());
```

Note, I renamed `array` to `data` since it is not an array but rather an object with an a property called posts that we access.

We use the `filter` method (Array.prototype.filter) to find the items in the array that we are interested in.

Since `filter` returns an array we access the first element.

If `filter` does not find any matching items, it returns an empty array and accessing the first element will return `undefined` so we check it before operating on it.

In newer runtimes we can express this more directly with the `find` method

```
const post3 = data.posts.find(post => post.id === 3);
```

Comment: @ToBe glad it helped. I updated it with some context and an alternative approach.

Answer (score -2):

you can do something like this:

```
array.posts.filter(item= > item.id === 3)[0].isReported = true;
```

Comment: Can you at least *explain the solution* if you're going to take it from the comments?

Comment: i'm using 'filter' method on the array to get certain record  (where id is 3) but this method returns array so i need to take only first record (thats why i using "[0]")